# Why are most of the LED lights for living dimmable just by their remote (they do not work with a wall dimmer)

Tags: led-strip, remote-control, dimming

I am trying to replace the lights in the entire house with LED lights with a more modern style like this one https://www.amazon.ca/dp/B09582MM2J. They all use LED strips and they say they are not dimmable unless you buy the version that comes with their own remote

Why is that ?

Comment: Those are light fixtures but not LED strips. The power supply must support dimming, which is slightly more expensive so not all cheaper devices have it.

Answer (score 1):

An incandescent light bulb is a piece of wire inside an evacuated bulb (actually, an argon-filled bulb these days).  When you put the right voltage on the bulb, the wire gets hot and it glows.

Dimmers that work with regular light bulbs chop the AC current going to the bulb so that it gets less power.  It runs cooler, and puts out less light.

An LED, by itself, is an electronic device that needs to have just the right current applied so that it will generate light.  In order to make one work off of house current, it needs driver electronics.

The *easiest* way to make these drive electronics is to make them take whatever the house electricity throws at them, and to generate steady light.  If you chop the AC going to them these simple drive circuits will either ignore what you're doing, or misbehave somehow.

"Dimmable" LED bulbs have drive circuits that are *built to recognize how a dimmer works*, and respond to it so the LEDs act as if they were an incandescent light.  That takes more circuitry, so they cost more.

That company has chosen to take another route, by selling you a remote for your lights instead of letting you use a wall dimmer.

Answer (score 0):

Incandescent bulbs can be dimmed with a simple dimmer because they can operate with varied voltages. They are powered directly from your home's mains typically 120ish volts in the US. The dimmer switch can variably "starve" them of power and they still light up but at a lower brightness. LEDs are light emitting diodes that are either forward biased and conducting or not. When LEDs are said to be dimmed, they are being turned fully on and off rapidly. The logic circuitry inside the "bulb" controls this and it expects a steady input voltage... That's the 500 ft view of it.

Comment: While PWM dimming is used especially for low voltage DC lighting like LED strips, it is more common that mains powered devices like in this question have current regulators that dim by reducing the current supplied to the load.